# .htaccess Url Rewrite stop my search function

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have set in .htaccess Url Rewrite
all working just my search function stop how to make working search function

my search URL is this

```
http://domain.com/index.php?a=search&q=word
```

but after submit search box url this and not work

```
http://www.domain.com/?a=search&q=word
```

how can i make search box work ?
my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?a=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?a=$1&q=$2&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?a=$1&q=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

my search form

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf">
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://www.domain.com/index.php" method="get">
<input name="a" type="hidden" value="search" />
        <input type="text" id="search" name="q" placeholder="Search here..." required>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

THanks

Comment: If you are redirecting all requests for `www.domain.com` to `domain.com`, why is your search form's action `http://www.domain.com/index.php`? Why not remove the www to avoid a redirect?

Comment: i have set form's action /index.php and also test without www but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got solutions by change

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf">
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/index.php" method="get">
<input name="a" type="hidden" value="search" />
        <input type="text" id="search" name="q" placeholder="Search here..." required>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Change TO

```
<div class="form-wrapper cf" >
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/index.php" method="get"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="a" type="hidden" value="search"/></div>
<input id="search" name="q" type="text"/>
<button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
</div>
```